# Prevent SQLite query from stripping leading zeros from numeric strings?

Tags: sqlite

In my database, a table contains two columns each containing an 8 digit ASCII code, usually it's just alphanumeric. For example, a row might contain `A123B45C` in col1 and `PQ2R4680` in col2.

I need to have a query/view that outputs a 4 character string calculated as the 2nd+3rd chars of these, concatenated. So in this example the extra column value would be `12Q2`.

This is a cut-down version of the SQL I'd like to use, although it won't work as written  because of zero stripping / conversion:

```
select

*, 
(substr(col1, 2, 2) || substr(col2, 2, 2)) AS mode

from (nested SQL source query) 

where (conditions)
```

This fails because if a row contains `A00B23B4` in col1 and `P32R4680` in col2, it will evaluate as `0032` and the query output will contain numeric `32` not `0032`. (It's worse if col1 contains `P1-2345` or "1.23456" or something like that)

Other questions on preventing zero stripping and string to integer conversion in Sqlite, all relate to data in tables where you can define a column text affinity, or static (quotable) data. In this case I can't do these things. I also can only create queries, not tables, so I can't write to a temp table.

What is the best way to ensure I get a 4 character output in all cases?

Comment: SQLite never modifies strings. Apparently, you are converting the values into numbers somewhere. Please provide a [mcve].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you issue is not with `substr` stripping characters as this works as expected e.g. :-

[image]

Then running query `SELECT  substr(col1,2,2) || substr(col2,2,2) as mode FROM stripping`

results in (as expected):-

[image]

Rather, your issue is likely how you subsequently utilise `mode` in which case you may need to use a CAST expression [CAST expressions](https://sqlite.org/lang_expr.html#castexpr)

For example the following does what is possibly happening :-

```
`SELECT  substr(col1,2,2) || substr(col2,2,2) as mode, CAST(substr(col1,2,2) || substr(col2,2,2) AS INTEGER) AS oops  FROM stripping`
```

resulting in :-

[image]